# How to exit loop when there's an error

Tags: r, loops

I have a loop in which I search for some value in a matrix. When no such value exits, the function will throw an error. I want to exit the loop when the error occurs. How do I do this?

I'm thinking something like this, but not sure how to execute in R.

```
for (i in 1:n){
val<-#find some value in an matrix
if (val returns error) break
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "val returns error"? From what you describe, are you looking for simple solution as: 
    `a = matrix(1:10,ncol=10)
    for (i in 1:length(a)) {
      if (a[i] != 1) break
      print(a[i])
    }`

Comment: `break`,  or `trycatch` , or several other methods.  But your main mistake is in allowing your matrix search to throw an error rather than returning, say, `NULL`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use tryCatch within R loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304940/use-trycatch-within-r-loop)

Comment: I tried `tryCatch` but couldn't figure out how to use `break` within the error handler without getting an error. If someone would like to show how to do that I'd be interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed do:

```
vec = c(1,2,3,5,6)

for(u in 1:10){
     if(!is.element(u, vec))
     {
         print(sprintf("element %s not found in vec", u)) 
         break
     }
     print(sprintf("element %s found in vec", u))
}

#[1] "element 1 found in vec"
#[1] "element 2 found in vec"
#[1] "element 3 found in vec"
#[1] "element 4 not found in vec"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `try`:

```
m <- matrix(1:16, 4)

for (i in 1:5){
  x <- try(m[i,i], silent = TRUE)
  if (inherits(x, "try-error")) break
  print(x)
}
#[1] 1
#[1] 6
#[1] 11
#[1] 16
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very useful :)))